# Python 3 and NLTK with WordNet 2.1 - is that possible?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I use Python 3 and NLTK 3.0.0 with WordNet 3.0.

I would like to use [this data (semeval2007)](https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/tree/master/pywsd/data/semeval2007_coarse_grain_wsd) with WordNet 2.1.

Is that possible to use WordNet 2.1 with Python 3?

Is that possible to replace WordNet 3.0 with WordNet 2.1? How can i do that?

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking into this too. But seems like the only way is to map WN2.1 to WN3.0 which is not an easy task.

Comment: Rada's page only have 1.6 to 2.0 and http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~mihalcea/downloads.html , the way to do the mapping is through https://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/sensemap.5WN.html  I've attempted but it's lossy, noisy mapping and manual annotation is required at some point...

Comment: Are you willing to use an older version of NLTK?

Comment: @DarrenCook yes, i am - can i use an older version of NLTK with Python 3?

Comment: Ah, I know NLTK around 2007 or 2008 used WordNet 2.1, but I have no idea if it will work with Python 3.

Comment: @DarrenCook NLTK 2 does not work with Python 3 due to many changes in Python 3, e.g. Python 3 has removed the separate unicode string object, see [NLTK 3 Changes](http://streamhacker.com/2014/12/02/nltk-3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use WordNetCorpusReader to load specific version of wordnet.

```
from nltk.corpus import WordNetCorpusReader

wn2 = WordNetCorpusReader("WordNet-2.0/dict", nltk.data.find("WordNet-2.0/dict"))

print wn2.get_version()
```