# How to fetch a specific version of Wordnet when doing nltk.download()

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I have a domain mapped file, for Wordnet synsets which is linked by offsets, from :- [link](http://wndomains.fbk.eu/)

This has two types of databases for different Wordnet versions and other significant differences. The readme says

```
- "wn-domains-3.2-20070223" contains the mapping between Princeton WordNet 2.0 synsets and their corresponding domains.
```

I am using python3.4 with Wordnet version 3 on a linux machine. I couldn't seem to find any other version of the domain file that would support Wordnet 3, so i need to to go for downgrading Wordnet to version 2. How do i do that?, is that even possible?

Comment: This was asked [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332454/python-3-and-nltk-with-wordnet-2-1-is-that-possible) a couple of years ago (but there's no answer.) But the [wordnet website](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/) provides a downloadable "sense-key mapping from version 2.1 to 3.0" (tgz [archive](http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/3.0/WNsnsmap-3.0.tar.gz)). Maybe you can use that to migrate your domain file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to roll back the nltk, you should migrate your resource to the current version of Wordnet -- if other project dependencies don't get in the way, of course. The [wordnet website](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/) provides a downloadable "sense-key mapping from version 2.1 to 3.0" ([tgz archive](http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/3.0/WNsnsmap-3.0.tar.gz)) that you can use to migrate your domain file to Wordnet 3.0. Each version of Wordnet contains a  similar migration table from the previous version, e.g. from [2.0 to 2.1](http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/2.1/WNsnsmap-2.1.tar.gz) (which apparently you needed), etc.